# Tslint rule for enforcing "typescript equivalent of package-scope"?

Tags: typescript, tslint

There is no "typescript equivalent of package scope", source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44101318/7123519.

The answer mentions that you can enforce it using tslint rules, however, it doesn't explain how to.

My question is just this: How do you create a rule that enforces package scope in Tslint?