# Are there any downsides of using 'export * from' in an index.ts file?

Tags: typescript

We are using index.ts to export all the symbols in that folder, that are exported by files in that folder.

Are there any risks to using `export * from <filename>;`?

Currently we use `export {item1, item2, item3} from <filename>;` which makes for extra manual effort to keep index.ts updated.

Comment: The risk will be to export a function that you don't want to. Anyway this won't make much difference at runtime unless you are exporting millions of functions instead of one.

Comment: I'll go with this as the answer "export a function that you did not intend to", but this in the form of a comment. Can you please create an answer instead? Also, i think that this question is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971951/typescript-equivalent-of-package-scope

Answer (score 1):

```
// a.ts
export const x = 123

// b.ts
export const x = 'qwe'

// c.ts
export * from './a.ts'
export * from './b.ts'
// ^ Module './a' has already exported a member named 'x'. Consider explicitly re-exporting to resolve the ambiguity.ts(2308)
```

is the only possible problem, and it errors, so there's none