How to have global TypeScript types defined specifically for tests (via @types/jest) that don't impact my application code
I just faced a bug on my project, related to TypeScript and having types specific to my tests.
I am using Jest to write my test, and have the jest type definitions installed via @types/jest. I have my type definitions for expect etc., who work globally.
Among these global testing functions, there is the fail() function (which is both defined globally at Jest runtime, and typed globally via @types/jest).
My problem: my project uses a custom fail() function a lot. It has nothing to do with testing, of course. And I just witnessed that some of my application code had fail() being used... but not the right one.
// import { fail } from '@my-own-app/fail' <- ❌ Oh no, I forgot this

...

function main() {
  fail(); // this crashes at runtime 
}

TypeScript does not report any error, because it thinks I am using the Jest fail function.
But I am not in a test file.
My question: how would you solve this? How would you have jest types that work only in *.test.ts files?
I could split the tsconfig.json in two (tsconfig.base.json with common properties, that derives into tsconfig.test.json + tsconfig.json).
That would work through CLI, if I run tsc twice (once for tests, once for app). But in that case, my IDE will not know that it should use tsconfig.test.json for *.test.ts files.
It's obviously a strong requirement that everything still works nicely in terms of DevX.
Any suggestion is welcome. My only idea right now that solves this while keeping a good DevX is to add an ESLint rule that specifically checks if fail() has been properly defined in my file.

Typescript does not support such a thing at the moment, it is recommended to use different names to avoid these overlaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971951/typescript-equivalent-of-package-scope

You can try having two separate tsconfig files. Exclude the jest typings in the default one and set jest to use the other one. (I think this is how). This might require some additional configuration to get your IDE to understand your setup

Thank you both. @TimHansen gave the answer. It simply is not supported

@apokryfos Thanks a lot. However, I had already mentioned your solution in my message. Unfortunately it won't work easily within the IDE...
